# Why my nested master page loses CSS formatting?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

My website structure is as follows

```
/Style.css
/MasterPage.Master
/Default.aspx

/Member/
  member.master
  member.aspx
```

The /MasterPage.Master points to style.css as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and it works like a charm.

After adding the `member.master` as a nested master page of `MasterPage.Master` i noticed that both the VS2010 and the rendered webpage, could not apply the formatting at the child `member.master`

After some googling i found that i could use the following code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("style.css") %>" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

The webpage is rendered correctly now, but how can i have the same result in design mode with the visual studio?

Comment: Some advice: there is never a scenario where nested master pages are mandated. It's a biatch to code and there is always a way to either create the same visual effect with CSS or logic/separation with one master and NuGet for sub projects.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, all paths should go as relative paths.

If you have the style sheet as

```
<link href="~/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the pages should work well. At the same time you need to have master pages referred as:

In your `member.master`:

```
MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
```

In `member.aspx`:

```
MasterPageFile="~/Member/member.master"
```

Hope this will help you.